# Bind a class to dynamic service property

Tags: ember.js, service, computed-properties

I have a service which I call `state` that just handles loading states and I can expand it to whatever I may want in the future. I needed this service so I could have different components talk to each other in a way so they would know if another component is loading or doing something.

Anyway I have this button that I use in different places that just sends an action, and then turns into a spinner until that action is complete.

They way the loading animation works currently is `classNameBindings: ['state.working'],`

However if I now have two of these buttons on screen at the same time, and I call `this.state.set('working',true);` all the buttons are now spinning.

I would rather pass in a property name to the button component that tells it what property to watch on the `state` service to determine if it should add the `working` class or not

I'm just having some trouble figuring out how to make this work in the component.

How can I have the class binding watch for a dynamic property name that will be passed to the component as something like `loadingPropertyName` so each button component can watch a different property for it's `working` class binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
init() {
  this.set('classNameBindings', 'state.'+this.get('stateProp'));
  this._super();
}
```